# Get currency exchange rate from bank site

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get content from bank site using curl.

`http://www.zaba.hr/home/wps/wcm/connect/zaba_hr/zabapublic/tecajna`

Site is specific becouse it using ajax to fill currency exchange table. There is a link for download data in to file but you have to have same session id to able to do that.

Im trying this code:

```
$url="http://www.zaba.hr/home/wps/wcm/connect/zaba_hr/zabapublic/tecajna";
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);
@$link = $dom->getElementById('tecajPrn');
echo $suburl = "http://www.zaba.hr".$link->getAttribute('href');
```

After this I got link to file but I can't open it.

Another strange situation is that link I got with curl is `http://www.zaba.hr/home/ZabaUtilsWeb/utils/tecaj/danasPrn` but real link when I click on icon is `http://www.zaba.hr/ZabaUtilsWeb/utils/tecaj/prn/62/2014`

Comment: If the currency content of the page is populated with an Ajax request, then emulate that ajax request, not the main page request; but check if they provide a public API first and use that if they do.... or find a site that does provide an exchange rate API

Comment: @samitha I tryed but table is empty becouse ajax fill it.

Comment: In the last sentence, you mean "the link I got with curl" or "the link I got with DOMDocument()" ?

Comment: @Antonio Ragagnin yes

Comment: @ikrajinovic, connect to the site with chrome, do `right click`->`inspect element` and then refresh the page. In the `network` tab you'll see there are some ajax requests that furnish the data you need in `JSON` (no need to parse `HTML`)

Comment: Can you please make it clear what you are trying to get?

Comment: @Mark Baker I'm not sure how to emulate AJAX request becouse I must have same SESSIONID accross all site otherwise I got error. Pls try to open link on Icon (small image "a") you will get this link `http://www.zaba.hr/ZabaUtilsWeb/utils/tecaj/prn/62/2014` and fill will be download to your computer. After that try to close your browser and paste that link in your address bar, you will get an error.

Comment: @majimboo I'm trying to get exchange rate date in any format

Comment: @ikrajinovic as to my knowledge what you are trying to do is kind of hard with php. Are you willing to try python to do this?

Comment: @Antonio Ragagnin Yes I can get data in `network` tab. But I can't open in `CHROME TAB`or programaticaly.

Comment: Did you check your/some central bank? They do quite often provide computer accessible (xml/csv) exchange rates for various currencies.

Comment: @ikrajinovic but if you will crawl the dom. Then it should work.

Comment: Yes, with central bank I can do that whit easy way `http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/hvazeca.htm` but my company work with "ZABA" bank and I must use their exchange rate.

Comment: @majimboo I'm not familiar whit crawl. Do you have some time to try that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing with cookie and ajax(may be!). Here is the lookaround. Try this:

First send a request to the page to obtain the cookie.

```
$url="http://www.zaba.hr/home/wps/wcm/connect/zaba_hr/zabapublic/tecajna";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "mozilla 5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

After that make another curl request. This time to obtain the json data:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "mozilla 5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", "Referer: http://www.zaba.hr/home/wps/wcm/connect/zaba_hr/zabapublic/tecajna"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.zaba.hr/ZabaUtilsWeb/utils/tecaj/danas");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Your json is available at this variable. Parse it using `json_decode()`

```
// now parse json from $cl
print $cl;
```

Anything required, help yourself straightway!

**Note:** Make sure you have write permission for the `cookie.txt` file. Also, its better to use absolute path like `c:/test/cookie.txt` or `/var/tmp/cookie.txt`.